# adding/deleting marker from gmaps

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I need to add/delete marker depending on checkox's state
here is my adding/deleting function(which doesn't work properly):

```
function getPointOnMap(mapObj) { 
    var position = new google.maps.LatLng(mapObj.lattitude, mapObj.longtitude);

    if(markers.length!=0){
        for(var i=0; i<markers.length; i++){
            if(markers[i].getPosition().toString() == position.toString()){
                marker.setMap(null);
                markers.slice(i);
            } else {
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ 
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(mapObj.lattitude, mapObj.longtitude), 
                    map: map });
                markers.push(marker);
            }
        }   
    } else {

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ 
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(mapObj.lattitude, mapObj.longtitude), 
            map: map });
        markers.push(marker);
    }
}
```

here is code of getting checkoxes and data for markers:

```
$.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url : "/getElements.json",
            success : function(result) {
            var html = '';
                for ( var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                    (function(n) {
                        var obj = result[i];
                        if (obj.field == 0) {
                            element = $("<input>", {
                            type : "checkbox",
                            id   : obj.id
                        });

                        element.click(function() {
                            getPointOnMap(obj);
                        });
                        $("#orders").append(element,
                            obj.address + "<br />");
                        }
                    })(i)
                }
            }
});
```

I need add/delete marker from map depending on checkbox state
so maybe someone would point where I have logical mistakes

Comment: What's the console saying? What is it doing or not doing?

Comment: In the second section. Why are you doing function(n) in the for clause?

Comment: @alkis second section works perfect. I just posted it to show it and nothing else

Comment: after some clicking on checkboxes console says "marker is undefined", when trying to delete it. it's logical, but how can I delete the existing marker from map, just knowing it's position?

Comment: I didn't say it's wrong. I asked why you did it as you did.

Comment: if(markers[i].getPosition().toString() == position.toString()){
                marker.setMap(null);

Shouldn't this be 
 if(markers[i].getPosition().toString() == position.toString()){
                markers[i].setMap(null);

Comment: @alkis, yes, it corrected deleting marker, but after deleting marker, no marker appers  :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31474/discussion-between-alkis-and-john-smith)

Comment: @alkis thanks for help, you've adviced useful tips, although the issue hasn't been solved yet :(

Comment: finally I found solution, I'll post the workaround later. thanks everybody for a fresh look from a side

Answer (score 0):

there was a logical mistake in cycle + misspelings in js functions.
here is fully workig functions which listens to checkbox's actions:

```
function getPointOnMap(mapObj) { 
        var position = new google.maps.LatLng(mapObj.lattitude, mapObj.longtitude);
        console.log(markers);
       var count = 0;


        if(markers.length!=0){
            for(var i=0; i<markers.length; i++){

                if(markers[i].getPosition().toString() == position.toString()){
                    count ++;
                    console.log("1");
                    markers[i].setMap(null);
                    markers.splice(i);
                } 
            }
            if(count==0) {
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ 
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(mapObj.lattitude, mapObj.longtitude), 
                    map: map });
                markers.push(marker);
            }
        } else {
            console.log("3");
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ 
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(mapObj.lattitude, mapObj.longtitude), 
                map: map });
            markers.push(marker);
        }
        console.log(markers);
}
```